# How to make VIM automatically insert closing delimiters and new lines like SUBLIME TEXT?

Tags: vimrc

While using Sublime Text, when I type the first parenthesis, bracket, or curly bracket, Sublime Text automatically does the second one for me.

> if(){}

```
if()
{
    Code
}
```

And while making an if statement, for loop, or while loop, when I move both the braces (curly brackets) to the next line and press Enter while my cursor is in the middle of the two braces, Sublime Text automatically puts the second brace in the next line and "tabs" my cursor in the middle of the two braces.

How can I configure VIM to do this? :)

Comment: There's a number of plugins that does this. I remember seeing a "plain" solution somewhere on here involving manual remaps, but even the plugins rarely include auto-formatting AFAIK.

Comment: One plugin you could look into is [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips)

Comment: Have you looked at delimitMate?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958357/vim-plugin-for-auto-closed-parenthesis for more information.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I just posted an answer below.. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Try looking into [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked question in the comments provides some options for what you're looking to achieve. In particular, without any plugins, one can use the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34993322/8696224)

```
inoremap ( ()<Left>
inoremap [ []<Left>
inoremap { {}<Left>
```

This accomplishes the automatic closing of parenthesis and brackets when you type `(`,`[`,`{`, in insert mode.

For your second question, it can also be done without any plugins:

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> search('{\%#}', 'n') ? "\<CR>\<CR>\<Up>\<C-f>" : "\<CR>"
```

Here's the breakdown:

```
inoremap <expr> <CR>         --- map the <CR> key using an expression
   search('{\%#}', 'n') ?    --- is the cursor ('\%#') between '{'and '}' ?
   "\<CR>\<CR>\<Up>\<C-f>"   --- if so, press <CR> twice, go <Up> a line, and autoindent (<C-f>),
   :                         --- otherwise, 
   "\<CR>"                   --- press <CR>.
```

This checks if the cursor is between `{` and `}`, but does *not* check if the previous line starts with `if`, `while`, or `for`. You can do so by modifying the `search()`. That is, instead of
`search('{\%#}', 'n')`, we can use `search('\(if\|while\|for\)\s*(.*)\s*$\n^\s*{\%#}', 'n')`.

For more, see

- `:h map-expr`
- `:h expr-quote`
- `:h pattern-overview`

Comment: OMG! Thank you, thank you, thank you!!! 
I can't upvote your answer enough!!!

Comment: Most welcome, happy to help :)